# The efficient and pythonic way to sort integers before strings

Tags: python-3.x, sorting

So I want to write an efficient sort in Python 3 that does this:

```
x = ["aa", "5", 5, "12", 12]
x.sort(key=???)

print x  // prints  [5, 12, "12", "5", "aa"]
```

It can imagine solutions, but they all involve dynamically constructing objects for each comparison, and they don't feel pythonic.

There must be a good design plan here, I am just not considering...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a key that returns the a unique value depending on the type, and then the value itself. I'm assuming you would want floats to be before strings as well, so let's say you want strings last and anything else first.

```
def strings_last(x):
    """When sorting, ensure strings are last."""
    if isinstance(x, str):
        return 1, x
    else:
        return 0, x

x = ["aa", "5", 5, "12", 12]
sorted(x, key=strings_last)
# [5, 12, "12", "5", "aa"]
```

Comment: This still amounts to dynamically constructing an object, but it is quite elegant.  I guess it is the best one can do in Python3.  Seems odd to me to remove the more general capability... I was thinking I was missing something...  I will wait a day to see if someone can generate a solution that does not perform dynamic object creation, but then accept this one if not.  thx!

Comment: @DanOblinger I realize it *seems* like this is less efficient because it is constructing new tuples for each element, but in reality it is WAY more efficient than `cmp`. With a `key`, every element in the original list is converted by the key once (an O(N) operation), and then it is that new list that is sorted. With `cmp`, for each comparison operation the cmp function must be called, which is at worst O(N^2). Since the overhead of calling a function is pretty large in python, using a key ends up being much more efficient than cmp.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you would still like to use a `cmp` function, you can convert it to a `key` function by importing `functools` and calling `functools.cmp_to_key` with the `cmp` function as an argument. Then, the returned `key` function can be provided to `sort`.